# Tensorflow JS Probabilties

Tags: tensorflow.js

i have multiple feature columns and a result column where i want to predict if something happens or not.
so I'm training my model and finally i do

```
const predictions = model.predict(xTest).argMax(-1);
```

this returns a tensor and when getting the data with:

```
predictions.dataSync ()
```

i get values like [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, ...]
is there any way to get probabilities like in python? [0.121, 0.421, 0.8621, ...]

I only found one result:
https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/tfjs/c/TvcB69MUj_I?pli=1

is this still the case? are there no probabilities in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.argMax` returns the indices of the maximum value along the axis. If you rather want to have the maximum value itself you could use `tf.max` instead

```
const x = tf.tensor2d([[1, 2, 3],[ 4, 8, 4]]);

x.max(-1).print()  // [3, 8]
x.argMax(-1).print() // [2, 1]
```